# I recently purchased a MacBook Pro 13.3" with a Retina display. Should I use a screen protector bought from Shopee as part of a casing package?

Tags: screen

I seem to have recalled some information from Apple some years ago which said that screen protectors for laptops and also iMacs were not recommended. I had an iMac at the time.

Comment: "Should I..." questions will get different opinions from different people. I would recommend asking about the pros/cons of using a screen protector on a laptop screen.